# Parse stats in ffprobe

Tags: parsing, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm gathering some metadata information of audio files using `ffprobe`. However, due to my unfamiliarity with this tool, I'm getting extra information that's not necessary. This is the command that I'm running:

```sh
ffprobe -f lavfi -i amovie=<audio_file>,astats=metadata=1:reset=4400 -hide_banner
```

This is a short sample output of what I'm getting:

```
Input #0, lavfi, from 'amovie=<audio_file>,astats=metadata=1:reset=4400':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3072 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_f32le, 48000 Hz, stereo, flt, 3072 kb/s
[Parsed_astats_1 @ 0x7fcfd4d01140] Channel: 1
[Parsed_astats_1 @ 0x7fcfd4d01140] DC offset: -0.032707
[Parsed_astats_1 @ 0x7fcfd4d01140] Min level: -0.041852
...
```

Is there a combination of flags that will produce a nice `JSON` or `CSV` output, hiding the `Input #0 ... and [Parsed_astats_1 @ 0x7fcfd4d01140]` like this:

```
{
    "Channel": 1,
    "DC offset": -0.032707,
    "Min level": -0.041852
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nicest solution I can come up with is using the `ametadata` filter and write the stats to a file.

```sh
$ ffmpeg -f lavfi -i sine -t 1s -af 'astats=metadata=1:reset=4400:metadata=true,ametadata=mode=print:file=stats' -f null -
$ cat stats
...
lavfi.astats.1.Bit_depth=16.000000
lavfi.astats.1.Bit_depth2=16.000000
lavfi.astats.1.Dynamic_range=78.265678
lavfi.astats.1.Zero_crossings=920.000000
lavfi.astats.1.Zero_crossings_rate=0.019965
lavfi.astats.Overall.DC_offset=0.000043
lavfi.astats.Overall.Min_level=-4095.000000
lavfi.astats.Overall.Max_level=4095.000000
lavfi.astats.Overall.Min_difference=0.000000
lavfi.astats.Overall.Max_difference=257.000000
lavfi.astats.Overall.Mean_difference=163.407865
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_difference=181.500114
lavfi.astats.Overall.Peak_level=-18.063656
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-21.073770
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_peak=-21.058020
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_trough=-21.118775
lavfi.astats.Overall.Flat_factor=0.000000
lavfi.astats.Overall.Peak_count=502.000000
lavfi.astats.Overall.Bit_depth=16.000000
lavfi.astats.Overall.Bit_depth2=16.000000
lavfi.astats.Overall.Number_of_samples=46080.000000
```

I guess your interested in the last frames `lavfi.astats.Overall.*` values.

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort, easier to parse!